# CSS not working properly in Svelte after importing "@smui/fab "?

Tags: javascript, sass, material-ui, svelte, rollupjs

When I put this line, all css inside my basic svelte app stops working.

```html
<script>
    import Fab from '@smui/fab';
</script>
```

All the elements are displaying properly. I can see Floating Action Button at the top left of the page but I am unable to move it to bottom right ?

Why is this happening?
How to sort this issue?

Comment: Spawn the browser devtools, inspect the loaded page, figure out, which styles are conflicting with each other. There's no universal fix for issues like that.

Comment: Or create a REPL with a minimal reproduction of your code. *CSS* errors are very hard to fix without debugging.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/issues/126

Comment: Check this link https://medium.com/@bekzatsmov/how-to-import-css-from-node-modules-in-svelte-app-2a38b50924ff